# Javascript: the elements of an array disappear after unshift method on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

After doing the method(unshift) on array the elements will gone why it's that ?

how can I return the elements that I did, on console

```
var ty=[8,7,6].unshift(10,9); //undefined

ty // 5

typeof(ty); // "number"
```

but in normal way it's working

```
var ty=[8,7,6]; // undefined

ty.unshift(2,1); // 5

ty // (5) [2, 1, 8, 7, 6]

typeof(ty); // "object"
```

How can I solve this .. thanks

Comment: `ty=[8,7,6].unshift(10,9)` stores the return value of `unshift` (which is the new length of the array) in `ty`. Code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

> The `unshift()` method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

After

```
var ty = [8, 7, 6].unshift(10, 9);
```

the assigned value is now the length of the array. Just as the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I want ask you how can I return the values of the array  in that case not the length

Comment: then you need to separate the statement into two, where you have the array, like `var ty = [8, 7, 6];` and later unshift some values, like `ty.unshift(10, 9);` where you drop the returned length of unshifting.

Comment: I already mention that in the question that I separate into two statements and that's in a normal way but I mean if I want in a one statement. How can I do that

Comment: var hgf=[8,7,6]; //undefined      and then                        

hgf=hgf.unshift(2,1); // 5                  and then   when I just type                                

hgf it just return me 5 how can I do so that it return   [8,7,6]   ??

Comment: but why the assignment?

Comment: You know because there are many methods in javascript  so instead for every method we write statement just with one statement... Or I say no problem......Sorry for disturbing you..... You have been absolutely kindly.... Thanks a lot.

Comment: no, i mean seriously why do you want an assignment of a result of shifting?

Comment: just don't care of that question.... I have another question how can I access variables inside a function ???